# how to use regex to replace the : character in encoded string?

Tags: java, regex

I have an encoded string with the syntax

```
"encodedProp:encodedValue OPERATOR encodedProp1:encodedValue1"
```

(the OPERATOR might be `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, and there are N pairs `prop:value`).

The `"encodedProp"`, `"encodedValue"`, `"encodedProp1"`, `"encodedValue1"` ... are the encoded strings.

I'd like to use a regular expression to replace the `":"` by `" = "`. Also, the part on the left side of `":"` should be replaced by `"\"" + left_part + "\""`, the right part should be replaced by `"'" + right_part + "'"`.

With the above example, the string after replacing should be:

```
"\"encodedProp\" = 'encodedValue' OPERATOR \"encodedProp1\" = 'encodedValue1'"
```

What is the expression I have to use to do this?

Comment: Surely you can format your question a little better? It's also hard to really tell what you want.

Comment: Don't just ask us to write code for you.  Show us the relevant pieces of code you have already, and ask specific questions about what you need help with.

Comment: need clarification about: 1) is there always 2 prop/value pair in the string? 2) is the operator always 'AND' 3) can encodedValue contain ':'

Comment: I used the regex: "(?i)(?<=^|\\s)\\*:\\*(?=\\s|$)" but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going out on a limb here because the problem is not well-defined, but let's give it a try.

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)(       # Match and capture in backreference number 1:\n" +
    " [^\\s:]+   #  one or more characters except spaces or colons\n" +
    ")           # End of capturing group 1\n" +
    ":           # Match a colon\n" +
    "(           # Match and capture in backreference number 2:\n" +
    " [^\\s:]+   #  one or more characters except spaces or colons\n" +
    ")           # End of capturing group 2", 
    "\"$1\" = '$2'");
```

This completely ignores the `OPERATOR` part - it simply looks for sequences of characters that include one colon, and wraps them in single/double quotes, replacing the colon along the way.